# grouping data using multiple values javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to parse this data into yearwise and monthwise based on channel name and date wise. If there is no order for particular month or particular date then the order count value of that month and date should be set as zero,

```
[
{
"ordersCount": 8,
"channel": "test-1",
"period": "4 Feb 2017"
},
{
"ordersCount": 4,
"channel": "test-1",
"period": "25 Feb 2017"
},
{
"ordersCount": 1,
"channel": "test-2",
"period": "24 Jan 2018"
}
]
```

my expected oputput is :

```
[
{
"channel": "test-1",
"Data": {
  "Year": [
    {
      "period": "Jan 2017",
      "orders": 0
    },
    {
      "period": "Feb 2017",
      "totalOrders": 12
    },{
      "period": "Mar 2017",
      "totalOrders": 0
    }...
  ],
  "Month": [
    {
      "period": "Jan 1",
      "totalOrders": 0
    },
    {
      "period": "Jan 2",
      "totalOrders": 0
    }
    ]
  }
 }
 ]
```

This is what I tried :
[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9de43ny/64/)

Comment: What do `Month` entries represent, exactly? `Jan 1` would mean the total number of orders for any 1st of January, no matter which year?

Comment: "Month" entries are the data of last 30 days from current date. i.e. data from june 25 th to july 25th of current year

Comment: So they should ignore anything with a 2017 period, for instance? (That seems weird.)

Comment: yes, we can ignore all other periods and that "Month" array should only contains order count of last 30 days.

Comment: But yet your `Year` entries can contain results from prior to one year ago? Since they seem to include dates such as January 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version handling only years (months should be easily doable from there).

Notes:

- I've changed the date to only take into account the last 12 months
  (see above comments), can be adjusted if need be.
- The dates (`period`) are in `year-month` format, which can be adjusted as well.

```js
const input = [{
  "ordersCount": 8,
  "channel": "test-1",
  "period": "4 Feb 2018"
},
{
  "ordersCount": 4,
  "channel": "test-1",
  "period": "25 Feb 2018"
},
{
  "ordersCount": 1,
  "channel": "test-2",
  "period": "24 Jan 2018"
}];

let result = {};

const twelveMonthsAgo = new Date(); twelveMonthsAgo.setMonth(twelveMonthsAgo.getMonth() - 12);

for (let entry of input) {   
  const entryDate = new Date(entry.period);
  
  if (entryDate >= twelveMonthsAgo) {
    result[entry.channel] = result[entry.channel] || { 
      channel: entry.channel, 
      data: { year: {}, month: {} } 
    };
      
    const monthKey = entryDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (entryDate.getMonth() + 1);
    if (!result[entry.channel].data.year[monthKey]) {
      result[entry.channel].data.year[monthKey] = {
        period: monthKey,
        totalOrders: 0
      };
    }
    
    result[entry.channel].data.year[monthKey].totalOrders += entry.ordersCount;
  }
}

result = Object.keys(result).map(channel => ({ 
  channel,
  data: {
    year: Object.values(result[channel].data.year), 
    month: []
  }
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: year array of expected output should contains order value for jul 2017 to jul 2018. Eg: "Year": [
        {
          "period": "Jul 2017",
          "totalOrders": 0
        },
        {
          "period": "Aug 2017",
          "totalOrders": 0
        },
        {
          "period": "Sep 2017",
          "totalOrders": 0
        },........
        {
          "period": "jun 2018",
          "totalOrders": 0
        },
        {
          "period": "jul 2018",
          "totalOrders": 0
        }],

Comment: You should easily be able to add missing months from there. I'll edit something in later if you can't find a way (no more time atm).

Comment: Thank you...It means a lot to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code, which gives output based on year, and month-wise in that year. Try running it in your browser console.

```
var incomingResponse  = [
 {
   "ordersCount": 8,
   "channel": "qoo10-SGD",
   "period": "4 Feb 2018"
 },
 {
   "ordersCount": 100,
   "channel": "qoo10-SGD",
   "period": "25 Feb 2018"
 },
 {
   "ordersCount": 12,
   "channel": "qoo10-SGD",
   "period": "25 Feb 2018"
 },
 {
   "ordersCount": 1,
   "channel": "lazada-MYR",
   "period": "24 Oct 2018"
 },
 {
   "ordersCount": 12,
   "channel": "lazada-MYR",
   "period": "25 Jun 2018"
 },
 {
   "ordersCount": 12,
   "channel": "lazada-MYR",
   "period": "4 Feb 2017"
 },
 {
   "ordersCount": 1,
   "channel": "magento-SGD",
   "period": "21 Feb 2018"
 },
 {
   "ordersCount": 3,
   "channel": "lazada-MYR",
   "period": "13 Oct 2018"
 }
];
function daysInMonth (month, year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

var result = {};
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
$.each(incomingResponse, function(key, value){
    var inputPeriod = value.period;
    var inputPeriodDate = new  Date(inputPeriod);
    var inputPeriodDateYear = inputPeriodDate.getFullYear();
    var inputPeriodDateMonth = inputPeriodDate.getMonth();

    // initializing default values based on channel for particular year period
    if( result[value.channel] == null || typeof result[value.channel] == 'undefined' ) {
        result[value.channel] = {'channel':value.channel, 'data':{'year':[]}};
    }

    // adding list of years as keys in above created year array
    if( result[value.channel]['data']['year'][inputPeriodDateYear] == null || 
        typeof result[value.channel]['data']['year'][inputPeriodDateYear] == 'undefined' ) {
        result[value.channel]['data']['year'][inputPeriodDateYear] = [];
    }

    // checking if data is present for particular year & particular month. If not present then creating default value set
    if( result[value.channel]['data']['year'][inputPeriodDateYear][months[inputPeriodDateMonth]] == null || 
        typeof result[value.channel]['data']['year'][inputPeriodDateYear][months[inputPeriodDateMonth]] == 'undefined' ) {
        result[value.channel]['data']['year'][inputPeriodDateYear][months[inputPeriodDateMonth]] = {'period':months[inputPeriodDateMonth] +' '+ inputPeriodDateYear, 'totalOrders':0, 'month': []};

        // retrieve number of days present in a month
        var numberOfMonthDays = daysInMonth((inputPeriodDateMonth + 1), inputPeriodDateYear);
        for(var dateCntr = 1; dateCntr <= numberOfMonthDays; dateCntr++) {
            result[value.channel]['data']['year'][inputPeriodDateYear][months[inputPeriodDateMonth]]['month'].push({'period': months[inputPeriodDateMonth] +' '+ dateCntr, 'totalOrders': 0});
        }
    }

    // before coming here, we already have default values present for year & month of selected input period.
    // so just adding up existing values of orders with order value coming from selected input period.
    result[value.channel]['data']['year'][inputPeriodDateYear][months[inputPeriodDateMonth]]['totalOrders'] = result[value.channel]['data']['year'][inputPeriodDateYear][months[inputPeriodDateMonth]]['totalOrders'] + parseInt(value.ordersCount);

    result[value.channel]['data']['year'][inputPeriodDateYear][months[inputPeriodDateMonth]]['month'][inputPeriodDate.getDate() - 1]['totalOrders'] = result[value.channel]['data']['year'][inputPeriodDateYear][months[inputPeriodDateMonth]]['month'][inputPeriodDate.getDate() - 1]['totalOrders'] + parseInt(value.ordersCount);
});
console.log(result);
```